# vbs script stops vba program

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a vba program that calls three different .vbs scripts. I can run it fine when the vbe window is open, but if I call it from a shortcut key, it opens the file from the .vbs script and stops.

How can I get it to release and continue the vba code?

Jerry Erwin

Comment: It's hard to be sure without knowing what your scripts do, but most likely you have commands that are being completed out of order due to the calls to vbs. Adding reasonable delays between calls will _probably_ solve the issue.